# GPS Coordinates translating

Tags: php, google-maps, gps

I am developing GPS tracking web site with a device from VisionTek with the model no 86VT

http://www.visiontek.co.in/vehicle-tracking-systems/86vt.html

I am able to get the device location but could not parse it correctly as we use in google maps.
For. Ex. I am getting the following longitude for Visakhapatnam which is 17.xxx in original Coordinate in google maps location.

17480249N

I dont know what is this format, and how to convert 17480249N to 17.xxx .
I also know that "N" is for positive values.

### Please help, I am using PHP, but any logic will be appreciated.

This is how I am getting the response from device. Please see the bold text for coordinates, I am near to Visakhapatnam beach.

$1,GlamourBik,14,11,10,14,40,08,**17434800N,083185195E**,02.1,13,0,0,A#

$2,GlamourBik,14,11,10,14,45,08,**17440069N,083187747E**,19.8,12,1,0,A#

$1,GlamourBik,14,11,10,16,53,42,**17440319N,083176376E**,00.3,178,1,0,A#

$1,GlamourBik,14,11,10,16,58,41,**17440319N,083176376E**,00.0,166,1,0,A#

$1,GlamourBik,14,11,10,17,03,42,**17440319N,083176376E**,00.0,42,1,0,A#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it is not Latitude ? (*N should mean North and Longitude is for East/West*)

In javascript this should probably do what you want..

```
function getUsable ( coordinate ) 
{
  var signMultiplier = {'S':-1,'N':1, 'W':-1, 'E':1};
  var sign = coordinate[ coordinate.length-1 ];
  return signMultiplier[sign] * parseInt(coordinate.replace( sign, '' ), 10) / 1000000;
}
```

using `getUsable('17480249N')` will return the google-map friendly version.

I assume that the format is an integer representation of six digit floating precision.

N is positive because it denotes North as opposed to South which should be negative.
Same for E (east) and W (west).

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Rjk8e/

---

**Update**

After your update with full coordinates and the answer from @wallyk, here is a version that can calculate the coords if they are in DMS format.

```
function getUsableDMS( coordinate )
{
    var signMultiplier = {'S':-1,'N':1, 'W':-1, 'E':1};
    var sign = coordinate[ coordinate.length-1 ];
    var length = coordinate.length-1;
    var D = parseInt( coordinate.substr(0,(length==8)?2:3), 10 );
    var M = parseInt( coordinate.substr(2,2), 10 );
    var S = parseInt( coordinate.substr(4,4), 10 ) / 100;
  return signMultiplier[sign] * (D + (M/60) + (S/3600));
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Rjk8e/1/

---

**Examples**

Is the first coordinate in your question ***17434800N***, ***083185195E*** located at any (*both are in the sea*) of

[google map using translation by first method](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=17.434800,83.185195&aq=&sll=17.666268,83.351898&sspn=0.809969,1.109619&ie=UTF8&ll=17.662343,83.248901&spn=1.619932,2.219238&z=9)
or
[google map using translation by DMS method](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=17.729999999999997,%2083.54033055555556&aq=&sll=13.531665,87.539586&sspn=13.194946,17.753906&g=17.729999999999997,%2083.54033055555556&ie=UTF8&ll=17.672811,83.251648&spn=1.619837,2.219238&z=9) ?

Comment: thanks Gaby, I am getting the values and its matching with the google but some inaccuracy about 1 KM. I dont understand the issue with device or the conversion code. I need to try from other location.

Comment: @Ajay, updated answer with a DMS translation as mentioned by @wallyk. Also posted the resulting point as google map. Can you verify if one of the two maps point to the correct location ?

Comment: As mentioned in both the cases we are getting the point inside the sea, where as I am on the beach or near to beach. May be issue with the device also as they mentioned that it may not be 100% accurate position.

Comment: @Ajay, indeed. Inaccuracy of the device might be a factor, but 1Km off seems like a long way (*but i am unaware of the specs and rules for GPS devices. It might be the standard..*). I suppose contacting the company for more info might be the prudent thing.

Answer (score 2):

[Visakhapatnam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visakhapatnam) is located at 17° 42′ N, 83° 15′ E  or, in signed decimal +17.7°, +83.25°.  Since Visakapatnam is fairly large, *17480249* probably means 17° 48' 2.49 ", which is about 2.5 km away EESE.

This is how GPS units format their data for the [NMEA 0183 bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA), for example.

Handle the quantities as a string.  For the latitude, use the first pair of digits as degrees, the second pair as minutes, the third pair as seconds, and any additional digits as digits after the seconds' decimal point.  For longitude, use the first three digits as degrees, and the remaining digits the same way as latitude.

To convert degrees, minutes, and seconds (DMS) to degrees, use the formula `D + M/60.0 + S/3600.0`.

Answer (score 1):

That format is nowhere on this page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion

My suggestion is to collect some data for some more cities and hope that you can pick out a pattern.